# Split the semicolon separated values into many columns and assign boolean 1 to the columns if the value matches to the column name else assign 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have data as semicolon-separated values present in one column called 'Primary Column' as highlighted below to a maximum of 12 unique values, I wanted to split these values in 12 such individual columns like bv, fv , iv etc and these individual columns should get populated either with 1 (if it matches to the Primary Column values) else 0 (if no match to the Primary Column values).

Primary Column Data

[image]

For Example,

if Primary Column has a data

> bv;fv;iv;kv;lr;lv;lz;mv;sh;sv;sz;wv;

then all the 12 individual columns should get populated with 1.

If Primary Column has a data bv;fv;iv; then only three individual columns (bv , fv , iv) should have Boolean value 1 and other column values should be 0.

and so on.

Please can you help me with a quick SQL Statement to achieve the above requirements?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Since nobody else mentioned it, you should consider fixing the data model here instead. Storing delimited values violates 1NF and is nothing short of aggravating and slow to work with.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `case` expressions.  In a `SELECT`, this would be:

```
select (case when col like '%bv%' then 1 else 0 end) as bv,
       (case when col like '%fv%' then 1 else 0 end) as fv,
       . . .
```

The above works assuming the "codes" are always two characters.

Or if the codes can be of variable length, take the delimiters into account:

```
select (case when ';' + col + ';' like '%;bv;%' then 1 else 0 end) as bv,
       (case when ';' + col + ';' like '%;fv;%' then 1 else 0 end) as fv,
       . . .
```

This can easily be incorporated into an `update` as well.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, simple case works fine for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative method, could also use `STRING_SPLIT` to normalise the data, and then use a conditional aggregate (aka a cross tab) to pivot it:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN SS.item = 'bv' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bv,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SS.item = 'fv' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS fv,
       ...
       MAX(CASE WHEN SS.item = 'wv' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS wv
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(YT.YourColumn,';') SS;
```

Personally, however, I would suggest fixing your design and normalising it.